# Sheet sorting macro (moving only selected sheets) not working

Tags: excel, vba

Been using the code below and it seemed to work just fine in the past until now...End goal is to sort selected sheets in a specific order.

```
Sub SortWksByCell()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim wss As Sheets

    Set wss = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    For i = 1 To wss.Count
        For j = i + 1 To wss.Count
            If UCase(wss(i).Range("q1")) <= _
                UCase(wss(j).Range("q1")) Then
                    wss(j).Move Before:=wss(i)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me.  What isn't working when you run it?

Comment: Its almost like it stops halfway through, but I'm not getting any errors. the sheets move around but in a nonsensical order. Note: I'm working with 60+ sheets.

Comment: OK - I only checked that the code ran successfully - I was relying on the first sentence in your question as implying that the logic was right and it was just an execution error, but it sounds like you have a logic error instead (and therefore it never worked, or only worked for a limited set of input conditions).  On looking at the code again, the sort won't work because you are never changing the positions of the sheets within `wss` - you are only changing their positions within the workbook.

Comment: ok thanks, how would I fix that?

Comment: It would be relatively easy if it was **all** sheets being sorted, but it's going to be trickier because you are only wanting to sort **selected** sheets.

Comment: I can make do with sorting all sheets, in sort of a beggars cant be choosers situation, so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Very, very, easy to sort **all** sheets.  (i.e. get rid of `Dim wss As Sheets` and `Set wss = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets`, and change all other `wss` to `Worksheets`)

Comment: Actually, it was even easier - just needed to change `Set wss = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets` to `Set wss = Worksheets`.

Answer (score 0):

To sort **all** worksheets, rather than **selected** worksheets, you can use:

```
Sub SortWksByCell()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim wss As Sheets

    'Set wss = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    Set wss = Worksheets
    For i = 1 To wss.Count
        For j = i + 1 To wss.Count
            If UCase(wss(i).Range("q1")) <= _
                UCase(wss(j).Range("q1")) Then
                    wss(j).Move Before:=wss(i)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I'll leave it to someone else to work out how to sort just the selected sheets.  (I need my morning coffee before I get into that.)